# Cell with text, formula and conditional formatting.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, conditional-formatting, formulas

I'm looking to see if you can add data to a cell, with a sum, and conditional formatting. An example.

```html
<table style="width: 308px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 122px;">A1</td>
<td style="width: 105.233px;">A2</td>
<td style="width: 200.767px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 122px;">100</td>
<td style="width: 105.233px;">120 (+20)</td>
<td style="width: 200.767px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I want cell A2 to show a new value (120) with the difference (+20) but also to have conditional formatting as in if the 120 in A2 is greater than the 100 in A1 then turn the cell green.

One option is to do the difference in cell A3 then use the CONCATENATE formula but this adds in another column and I cannot establish how to run Conditional Formatting from that.

Comment: Unless you want the user to have to edit the formula to enter the value in more than one place, you'd need to get the value from another cell... I'd suggest this be two cells with a white background so you can't see the cell division grid. You can then have `C1` containing something like `="("&IF(B1-A1>0,"+"&B1-A1,B1-A1)&")"`...   The conditional formatting will be easy to tie to `=B1>A1` for green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming A1 contains `100` (or any other number) and A2 `120 (+20)` (or anything of the style `N (+/-N)` where N is a string of numeric characters).

Please clear any existing conditional formatting, select A2 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=--LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))>A1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your green format <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.